# Microsoft Access 2003 - Multiple checkboxes to fill a text field

Tags: microsoft-access

I am using Access 2003, I am looking for help with using checkboxes in a form to fill a text field.

I am using the following code to get the checkbox to fill a text field.

```
Private Sub CAN_Click()
If Me.CAN = -1 Then
    Me.[Subdirectorate Services] = "Community Adult Nursing"
    Else
    Me.[Subdirectorate Services] = ""
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I have approx 20 checkboxes to record a range of different services and multiple options can be selected.The above code works fine when a checkbox is selected and transfers the required text to the text field, but when another checkbox is selected the previous entry in the text box is overwritten.

How can I get the textbox to be updated with multiple entries?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`Me.[Subdirectorate Services] = "Community Adult Nursing"`
you can use
`Me.[Subdirectorate Services] = Me.[Subdirectorate Services] & ", " & "Community Adult Nursing"` 
to concatenate multiple values.

For your whole code logic (not correct code) would be:

```
Me.[Subdirectorate Services]=""  
If Me.CAN = -1 Then _ 
   Me.[Subdirectorate Services] = Me.[Subdirectorate Services] & ", " & "Community Adult Nursing"
If Me.CAN2 = -1 Then _  
   Me.[Subdirectorate Services] = Me.[Subdirectorate Services] & ", " & "text 2"
...
If Me.[Subdirectorate Services] <> "" then _  
   Me.[Subdirectorate Services] = Left(Me.[Subdirectorate Services]="",Len(Me.[Subdirectorate Services]="")-2)
```

Last row is to remove `,` from the end of the string.

Comment: I have updated my code and this allows me to have all the ticked boxes displayed in the text box. I have a new question now, if one of the ticked boxed is unticked then all the text is removed from the text box, how do I ensure that only the text relating to the unticked check box is removed?

Comment: This field is not backfilling the table, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I've updated my code, hopefully it'll be an answer for your first comment. Second comment should be asked in a new question:)